# Laravel 5.4 method not allow on patch

Tags: methods, routes, laravel-5.4

I'm working on updating the data through a PATCH form, the form is working on localhost, but it is not working on server, i have check the route list the route i create is using the PATCH method also, but laravel return me a method not allow exception, here is my code:

Controller:

```
public function registercert (Request $request, $id) {
      // return $request->all();
      $user = User::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::patch('admin/user/registercert/{id}', ['as'=>'registercert', 'uses'=>'admin\AdminUserController@registercert']);
```

[image]
View:

```
 {!! Form::open(['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=>['admin\AdminUserController@registercert',$user_id], 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
...
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it using a "regular" form with a POST method and adding laravel's method spoofing

```
<form class="form" action="/clientes/{{ $cliente->id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   {{ method_field('PUT') }}
   @include('partial.cliente-campos')
</form>
```

The important part here is the `method="POST"` in the form and the `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`. You need both.